# Simplest way to distribute Tensorflow training on premise?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, kubernetes, distributed-computing, google-cloud-ml

What is the simplest way to train tensorflow models (using Estimator API) distributed across a home network? Doesn't look like ml-engine [local train](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/ml-engine/local/train) allows you to specify IPs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to use something like Kubernetes. This is a work in progress, but I believe it does have support for distributed training as well -- https://github.com/tensorflow/k8s.

Alternatively for more low-tech automation options, these come to mind...

1. You could have a script which still uses SSH and executes a script remotely.
2. You could have the individual workers poll a shared location for a file to use as a signal to download and execute a script.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the environment variable [TF_CONFIG](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/estimator/run_config.py), which will be parsed by estimators.

Comment: I get how it works. But what's the easiest way to do that? I don't want to ssh into every machine, do a git pull, and run the scripts by hand...